# How to convert csv file to python dictionary?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a huge csv file containing information about COVID-19 cases and deaths for every single county in the United States.

To give you a general idea of the information contained in this file, here are the first 10 lines of it:

```
date,county,state,fips,cases,deaths,confirmed_cases,confirmed_deaths,probable_cases,probable_deaths
2021-03-18,Autauga,Alabama,01001,6483,96,5557,85,926,11
2021-03-18,Baldwin,Alabama,01003,20263,295,14329,220,5934,75
2021-03-18,Barbour,Alabama,01005,2199,54,1225,37,974,17
2021-03-18,Bibb,Alabama,01007,2512,58,2031,35,481,23
2021-03-18,Blount,Alabama,01009,6371,129,4901,109,1470,20
2021-03-18,Bullock,Alabama,01011,1193,39,1059,29,134,10
2021-03-18,Butler,Alabama,01013,2069,66,1888,60,181,6
2021-03-18,Calhoun,Alabama,01015,14137,301,10608,242,3529,59
2021-03-18,Chambers,Alabama,01017,3460,113,1720,73,1740,40
```

Anyways, I want to create a Python dictionary for this data with each of the keys being a tuple consisting of the state and county names and the each of the values being a list of integers: the first `int` representing the number of confirmed cases and the second one representing the number of confirmed deaths.

Basically, I want output like this:

```
dic = {("state","county"):[confirmed_cases, confirmed_deaths]}
```

Please make sure to exclude the header.

How would I generate a python dictionary like the one above for all the counties in the csv file? Please use `csv.reader`.

Additionally, I need to find the sum of all the confirmed deaths for a particular state. How would I, for example, sum up the values in 'confirmed deaths' for all of the rows where 'state' is 'Alabama'?

EDIT: I came up with a solution for the first part of the problem:

```
mydict = {}

with open(file_path, mode='r') as inp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    next(reader,None)
    mydict = {tuple(row[1:3]):list(row[6:8]) for row in reader}

return mydict
```

Can you help me figure out how to sum up confirmed deaths in a certain state based on this dictionary?

Comment: You can use module `csv` to save your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import csv

mydict = dict()
with open("test.csv") as inp:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    next(reader, None) #skip header
    mydict = {tuple(row[2:0:-1]): list(map(int, row[6:8])) for row in reader}

#total of all confirmed deaths in Alabama
>>> sum(v[1] for k, v in mydict.items() if k[0]=="Alabama")
890
```

###### test.csv:

```
date,county,state,fips,cases,deaths,confirmed_cases,confirmed_deaths,probable_cases,probable_deaths
2021-03-18,Autauga,Alabama,01001,6483,96,5557,85,926,11
2021-03-18,Baldwin,Alabama,01003,20263,295,14329,220,5934,75
2021-03-18,Barbour,Alabama,01005,2199,54,1225,37,974,17
2021-03-18,Bibb,Alabama,01007,2512,58,2031,35,481,23
2021-03-18,Blount,Alabama,01009,6371,129,4901,109,1470,20
2021-03-18,Bullock,Alabama,01011,1193,39,1059,29,134,10
2021-03-18,Butler,Alabama,01013,2069,66,1888,60,181,6
2021-03-18,Calhoun,Alabama,01015,14137,301,10608,242,3529,59
2021-03-18,Chambers,Alabama,01017,3460,113,1720,73,1740,40
```

Comment: Thanks. How would I add up the confirmed_deaths for each state?

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but for some reason the code you put in is not working. However, I just came up with code that is working as I intended:                         
  mydict = {}

    with open(file_path, mode='r') as inp:
        reader = csv.reader(inp)
        next(reader,None)
        mydict = {tuple(row[1:3]):list(row[6:8]) for row in reader}

    return mydict

Comment: Can you please come up with a new sum function based on my code?

Comment: When I tried your code for the dictionary part, I kept on getting error messages. However, I just figured out a solution for the part of the problem where I have to generate a dictionary from the csv. I edited the OP to include it. Can you please help me find the sum of confirmed deaths for a particular state in the dictionary created by my function? Thank you!

Comment: @Answersplease - My code gives me no errors with the sample .csv you provided. I have no idea what errors you're getting or how. Also, the code to get the sum shouldn't change if your dictionary structure is the same. It's just the last line of my answer. Note that in your dictionary you're saving `dic[("county", "state")]` but you mentioned in your post that you want `dic[("state", "county")]`

Comment: @Answersplease - I edited my code to be as similar as possible to what you already have. Just use the last line of code for the `sum` you need. Note that my dictionary has `dic[("state", "county")]` unlike yours (`dic[("county", "state")]`). Also, your numerical values are likely being saved as strings instead of numbers. Mine are numbers. Please retry my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think pandas is the most appropriate solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
dict = df.set_index(['county','state'])[['confirmed_cases', 'confirmed_deaths']].apply(tuple, axis = 1).to_dict()
print(dict)
```

**EDIT**

for the sum part:

```
sum = df.groupby(['state'], as_index=False)['confirmed_cases', 'confirmed_deaths'].sum()
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually do it a different way, albeit a bit more verbose but more readable by someone looking at the code.

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple

County = namedtuple("County", ["name", "cases", "deaths"])
reader = csv.DictReader(data)

for row in reader:
    state = row["state"]
    county = row["county"]
    record = County(county, int(row["confirmed_cases"]), int(row["confirmed_deaths"]))
    if state in states:
        states[state].append(record)
    else:
        states[state] = [record]

{'Alabama': [County(name='Autauga', cases=5557, deaths=85),
  County(name='Baldwin', cases=14329, deaths=220),
  County(name='Barbour', cases=1225, deaths=37),
  County(name='Bibb', cases=2031, deaths=35),
  County(name='Blount', cases=4901, deaths=109),
  County(name='Bullock', cases=1059, deaths=29),
  County(name='Butler', cases=1888, deaths=60),
  County(name='Calhoun', cases=10608, deaths=242),
  County(name='Chambers', cases=1720, deaths=73)]}

sum(county.deaths for county in states["Alabama"])
>> 890
```

It will be easier to manage your code if you keep the key simple, in this case just the state. This will also be quicker if your data is larger since we won't have to iterate over tuple keys in the dictionary to grab the state we want.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a dictionary of dictionary. It then becomes easier to get totals by state or county. I used 2 dictionaries: `dd` is the dict of dict and `deaths` is a dictionary built from the `dd` dictionary to get the deaths by state.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(dict)

with open('csv_11_09_01.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    for record in reader:
        dd[ record['state'] ][ record['county'] ] = \
           [
               int(record['confirmed_cases']),
               int(record['confirmed_deaths'])
            ]
```